# How to ssh in to BSD vm as root

Tags: macos, ssh, freebsd, vmware-fusion

I'm using vmware fusion pro 7 on OS X 10.10. I'm having trouble ssh-ing in to my vm as root. The process is simple `ifconfig` pull ip. Open terminal window `ssh root@ip`. However I can't seem to gain root access to my vm. I'm 100% positive everything is networking correctly as I am able to gain access with my username using the exact same process.

Comment: what have you done? How do you have set up network? Are you getting some errors?

Comment: I setup my BSD vm like usual. SSH is standard on BSD so no need to install anything. From my understanding you are supposed to pull your ip with ifconfig... So I did that copied my ip to clipboard. The guide I was reading said to ssh localhost / then ssh with the ip from the vm. I did that and tried to access my vm by ssh@vm_ip in the terminal window but it's not returning anything. The setup is very basic I'm using an ISO image of freebsd and VmWare Fusion Pro which I am trying to access through terminal. NAT is default on the VM. NO errors! Just doesn't work?

Comment: are you able to ping the ip? What is the status of sshd service on bsd machine? `service sshd status` Are you able to connect to service from the BSD terminal (with ip and with `localhost`)? What are the exact commands you are using? Can you please update these (and previous) information into the original question. It is really hard to read through the comments without formatting.

Comment: Basically everything works as it should once you spin up the VM you just [ifconfig] using the em0 ip address open terminal and [ssh username@ip] directly in to the server. The only caveat is I was unable to ssh as root however this is just a minor annoyance as I can easily enter su mode once I'm in.

Comment: So completely different question. Please, update your question. You are not able to ssh as a root. I guess current BSD has default option in `sshd_config` called `PermitRootLogin=no` or `PermitRootLogin=prohibit-password`. If you change it to `yes`, it will work.

Comment: @Jakuje This is true. That will be my first order of business. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Jakuje Works Perfectly! Again thanks for the advice much appreciated.

Comment: And for the next time, it would be more fair to let me till the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ssh in to your vmware host from the terminal on your mac this is how you do it. Disclaimer I'm using a mac + vmware fusion pro 7, I can't predict how this will work on anything outside of that.

Once you spin up your BSD vm simply type the `ifconfig` command. Look at the first block of code em0 and copy or write down the ip address. It's not the one at the bottom just to be clear it's in the top block.

After you have your ip open your terminal window simply type `ssh username@ip`! Thats it! You should be inside of your vm now. I'm working on root access haven't been able to ssh in yet using root. Hope this helps!

Simply change the root access in the `nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config` to enable root access.

Comment: +1 for the last line. Direct root (or toor) access is disabled by default. One is supposed to login as a normal user and su or sudo when needed.